# Adjust CLANG/LLVM compiler flags to turn off auto-vectorization for a loop that only ever runs a few iterations

Tags: c++, optimization, clang, compiler-optimization

I need to disable a CLANG/LLVM optimization flag because it's creating a bloated output, specifically over-aggressive vectorization.

I have the following code sample:

```
typedef                     unsigned char               uint8;
typedef                     unsigned long               ulong;
typedef                     unsigned long long int      uint64;
typedef                     unsigned long long int      size_t;

ulong inline /*__attribute__((optnone))*/ SetMemberMask(uint8* const stream, size_t const length)
{
    size_t                  pos = 0;
    uint64                  compose{};

    do
    {
        auto                bit = stream[pos];

        compose |= 1ULL << bit;
    } while (++pos <= length);

    return compose;
}

uint64 BitFieldStreamMasks_64(uint8* const __restrict p_stream, size_t const p_qry_rows, uint64* const __restrict p_comparand, uint64* const __restrict p_masks)
{
    auto const              bits = static_cast<size_t>(p_stream[0]);
    auto const              memberCount = static_cast<size_t>(p_stream[1]);
    auto const              bitOrderedIx = &p_stream[0];
    auto const              sectionSortedIx = &bitOrderedIx[bits];
    uint64                  stream = SetMemberMask(p_stream, memberCount);

    return stream;
}
```

The code is in Compiler Explorer [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MGMjdav93).

The issue exists with `SetMemberMask()`. With ICC 2021.6.0 and flags "`-xCORE-AVX2 -O3`", the body of this function compiles to the following:

```
movzx     ecx, BYTE PTR [rdx+rdi]                       #13.17
inc       rdx                                           #9.20
bts       rax, rcx                                      #15.3
cmp       rdx, rsi                                      #9.20
jl        ..B2.6        # Prob 82%                      #9.20
```

This is exactly as expected.

With CLANG 15.0.0, flags "`-march=x86-64-v3 -O3`", I get:

```
        vpmovzxbq       ymm5, dword ptr [rdi + rdx] # ymm5 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpmovzxbq       ymm6, dword ptr [rdi + rdx + 4] # ymm6 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpmovzxbq       ymm7, dword ptr [rdi + rdx + 8] # ymm7 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpmovzxbq       ymm8, dword ptr [rdi + rdx + 12] # ymm8 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpsllvq ymm5, ymm4, ymm5
        vpor    ymm0, ymm5, ymm0
        vpsllvq ymm5, ymm4, ymm6
        vpor    ymm1, ymm5, ymm1
        vpsllvq ymm5, ymm4, ymm7
        vpor    ymm2, ymm5, ymm2
        vpsllvq ymm5, ymm4, ymm8
        vpor    ymm3, ymm5, ymm3
        vpmovzxbq       ymm5, dword ptr [rdi + rdx + 16] # ymm5 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpmovzxbq       ymm6, dword ptr [rdi + rdx + 20] # ymm6 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpmovzxbq       ymm7, dword ptr [rdi + rdx + 24] # ymm7 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpmovzxbq       ymm8, dword ptr [rdi + rdx + 28] # ymm8 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpsllvq ymm5, ymm4, ymm5
        vpor    ymm0, ymm5, ymm0
        vpsllvq ymm5, ymm4, ymm6
        vpor    ymm1, ymm5, ymm1
        vpsllvq ymm5, ymm4, ymm7
        vpor    ymm2, ymm5, ymm2
        vpsllvq ymm5, ymm4, ymm8
        vpor    ymm3, ymm5, ymm3
        add     rdx, 32
        add     rax, -2
        jne     .LBB0_6
        test    r8b, 1
        je      .LBB0_9
.LBB0_8:
        vpmovzxbq       ymm4, dword ptr [rdi + rdx] # ymm4 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpmovzxbq       ymm5, dword ptr [rdi + rdx + 4] # ymm5 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpmovzxbq       ymm6, dword ptr [rdi + rdx + 8] # ymm6 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpmovzxbq       ymm7, dword ptr [rdi + rdx + 12] # ymm7 = mem[0],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[1],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[2],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,mem[3],zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero
        vpbroadcastq    ymm8, qword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # ymm8 = [1,1,1,1]
        vpsllvq ymm4, ymm8, ymm4
        vpor    ymm0, ymm4, ymm0
        vpsllvq ymm4, ymm8, ymm5
        vpor    ymm1, ymm4, ymm1
        vpsllvq ymm4, ymm8, ymm6
        vpor    ymm2, ymm4, ymm2
        vpsllvq ymm4, ymm8, ymm7
        vpor    ymm3, ymm4, ymm3
.LBB0_9:
        vpor    ymm1, ymm1, ymm3
        vpor    ymm0, ymm0, ymm2
        vpor    ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vextracti128    xmm1, ymm0, 1
        vpor    xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        vpshufd xmm1, xmm0, 238                 # xmm1 = xmm0[2,3,2,3]
        vpor    xmm0, xmm0, xmm1
        vmovq   rax, xmm0
        jmp     .LBB0_10
```

If I remove `-march=x86-64-v3` or turn `-O3` down to `-O1`, the output is close to that of ICC.

What do I need to add to the compiler setting to disable whatever is causing this overly aggressive vectorization? I can use the `__attribute__((optnone))` attribute, which works, but I want to disable this optimization project-wide.

EDIT: I need the disable version of `-fno-slp-vectorize`, or the full set of what `-march=x86-64-v3` enables.

Comment: `-march=x86-64-v3` enables `-mavx2` as the relevant option for making this vectorizable.  It's the other options that tell clang how to attempt to use those available instructions; you probably don't want to use `-mno-avx2` unless there's nothing else in your code that can profitably vectorize with AVX2 instructions.  `-fno-tree-vectorize`  (GCC/clang) or `-fno-vectorize` for clang specifically should block that vectorization.

Comment: It looks pretty reasonable and profitable unless the array of bit-numbers is small, in which case maybe you can just hint clang about the expected value-range with `__builtin_expect` or something.  Maybe a bit excessive in amount of unrolling

Comment: @PeterCordes The expected count is around 5. `-fno-vectorize` works, although the code differs considerably from the ICC version. Would you mind posting an answer with the `__builtin_expect` option? I'm not familiar with how to use it correctly.

Comment: I haven't used it for this, only for `likely`/`unlikely` macros, but I think clang has a way 
to give it hints about values, or even promises.  If I get to it, I'll have a look tomorrow.  Like maybe `if(len>15) __builtin_unreachable();`, although if you also build with ICC, I think it wastes instructions to actually compare and branch to nowhere, entirely defeating the purpose of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @PeterCordes I discovered that `#pragma nounroll` will tame the optimization considerably and result in output *very* close to that of ICC. `-fno-vectorize` alone results in lengthy, unintuitive code IMO. However, the two options combined result in a mere 5 ASM ops loop, as expected.